# New Orion Context Broker release (0.24.0) is available

Tags: fiware-orion

Fiware released last version 0.24.0;
please can you provide a link for virtual box VM ?
When do you think it will be solid for production ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to VirtualBox VM is: http://bit.ly/fiware-orion-vbox. Please have a look to the [Orion slideshare presentation](http://bit.ly/fiware-orion) around slide number 32 about it (e.g. user/password to login). This VM has an old Orion version installed, so you have to [upgrade it](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.org/en/develop/admin/install/index.html#upgrading-from-a-previous-version) (typically using `yum install contextBroker`).

Let me clarify that 0.24.0 is perfectly solid for profuction as long as you use the NGSIv1 API (i.e. the one corresponding to the `/v1` URLs in the REST API). What is yet in beta status in only the part correspondig to NGSIv2 API (i.e. the one corresponding to the `/v2` URLs in the REST API).

Comment: Also keep in mind that you need to configure port forwarding in the machine to open por 1026 (port 22 is already forwarded to 2222 on the host).

Comment: When do you think NGSIv2 will be OK for production ?

Comment: Difficult to say :)... It will be ok when all the NGSIv2 operations have been fully specified and implemented (you can check the progress at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f4m624nmO3jRjNalGE11lFLQixnfCENMV6dc54wUCCg/edit#gid=50130961) and some time passes to assure that everything works without problems.